# Yii CCheckBoxColumn validation in client side (Java Script)

Tags: javascript, php, validation, yii

Hi Iam using CCheckBoxColumn in CGridView. I want to check at least one check box value should be selected before submit a form. how to write a rules for this.

Following is the code.
view.php

```
    'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn', 'selectableRows' => 2,
    'checkBoxHtmlOptions' => array(
        'name' => 'custids[]',
        'value'=>'CHtml::checkBox("cid[]",null,array("value"=>$data->customer_id,
        "id"=>"cid_".$data-customer_id
     ))',
     'type'=>'raw',
  ),
```

In Moduls

```
public function rules()  {   // NOTE: you should only define rules for
those attributes that   // will receive user inputs. return array( ...
....  array('custids', 'CheckSelected' ), ... }


public function CheckSelected($attribute,$params ) {
    if(count($this->custids) == 0)
           $this->addError($attribute,'Please select the cust ids'); }
```

How to validate this checkbox[] in client side.

I have tried with the examples mentioned in  [Validate Or Limit Number Of Checkboxes Selected In Ccheckboxcolumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/35860-validate-or-limit-number-of-checkboxes-selected-in-ccheckboxcolumn/) links.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this check in afterValidate client option

```
$form = $this->beginWidget(
         'CActiveForm',
         array('id' => 'add_category_form',
             'enableAjaxValidation' => true, 
             'clientOptions' => array(
             'validateOnSubmit' => true, 
                 'ajaxVar' => 'ajax', 
                 'afterValidate' => "js: function(form, data, hasError) {

                    ///check it there
                    return false;
                }
                "
             )
         )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the code for your active form, but you can always check this in client side by only letting the form to submit if at least one of the checkboxes is checked,

you can [retrieve the checked column in client side (javasctipt)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCheckBoxColumn#selectableRows-detail):

```
 var idArray = $(gridID).yiiGridView('getChecked', columnID);
 // or
 $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(gridID);
```

now you can stop if this is an empty array.

Comment: this is javascript, use it before sending your form data

Comment: Can you plese provide sample code for where and how to use this javascript ?